# MEAN GET http://localhost:8000/user/undefined 500 (Internal Server Error)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mongoose, mean-stack

Have reviewed other answers and none have to help. Just trying to get the username to appear on my main page. It works for the other pages. Probably something easy I have missed but I've stared at this long enough.
Main page to get it rendered:

```html
<div ng-controller="dashboardController" flex layout="column" layout-align="center center">

<md-toolbar>
      <div class="md-toolbar-tools">
        <h1>
          <span>Welcome {{user.username}}</span>
        <h2>
          <span>NAME OF MY THIS SITE</span>
        </h2>        
        <span flex></span>
        <md-button ng-click="logout()" aria-label="Log Out">
          Log Out
        </md-button>
      </div>
</md-toolbar>
</div>
```

Main page controller:

```js
kelvindashdemo.controller('dashboardController', ['$scope', 'UserFactory', '$routeParams', '$location', 'TopicFactory', function($scope, UserFactory, $routeParams, $location, TopicFactory){
 UserFactory.getUser($routeParams.id, function(user){  //makes request to backend and sets $scope to the user id
  $scope.user = user;
  console.log($routeParams);
 })
 $scope.logout = function(){
     UserFactory.logout();
 }
 
 TopicFactory.getTopics(function(topics){
  $scope.topics = topics;
 })
 $scope.createTopic = function(topic){
  TopicFactory.createTopic(topic, function(){
   TopicFactory.getTopics(function(topics){
    $scope.topics = topics;
    $scope.newTopic = {};
   })   
  })
 }
}])
```

UserFactory:

```js
kelvindashdemo.factory('UserFactory', ['$http','$location', function($http, $location){
 var factory = {};
 factory.login = function(user, callback){
  $http({
   method:"POST",
   data:user,
   url:'/login'
  }).then(function success(res){
   callback(res);
  }, function error(res){
   console.log(res);
  });
 }
 factory.register = function(user, callback){
  $http({
   method:"POST",
   url:'/register',
   data:user
  }).then(function success(res){
   callback(res);
  }, function error(res){
   console.log(res);
  });
 }
 factory.getUser = function(userId, callback){
  $http({
   method:"GET",
   url:'/user/'+userId
  }).then(function success(res){
   callback(res.data);
  })
 }
 factory.logout = function(){
    $http({
      method: 'GET',
      url: '/logout',
    }).then(function(res){
      if (res.status == 200){
        $location.url('/login');
      }
    })
  }
 return factory;
}])
```

Routes:

```js
var Users = require('../controllers/Users.js');
var Topics = require('../controllers/Topics.js');
var Answers = require('../controllers/Answers.js');
var Comments = require('../controllers/Comments.js');

module.exports = function(app){
 app.post('/login', Users.login);
 app.post('/register', Users.register);
 app.get('/logout', Users.logout);

 app.use(loginAuthentication);
 //Protected API
 app.get('/user/:id', Users.get);

 app.get('/topics', Topics.getAll);
 app.post('/topics', Topics.createNew);
 app.get('/topic/:id', Topics.get);

 app.post('/topic/:id/answers/', Answers.createNew);
 
 app.get('/comments/likes/:id', Comments.like);
 app.get('/comments/dislikes/:id', Comments.dislike);
 app.post('/answers/:id/comments', Comments.createNew);
}

function loginAuthentication(req,res,next){
 if (req.session.user){
  next();
 }else{
  res.status(401).send("User is not logged in");
 }
}
```

Server side UsersController:

```js
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var User = mongoose.model('User');


module.exports = {
 register: function(req,res){
  /* username:? , password:?, passwordconfirm:? */
  if (req.body.password != req.body.password_confirm){
   console.log("These passwords dont match");
   return res.sendStatus(400);
  }
  var user = new User(req.body);
  user.save(function(err, user){
   if (err){
    console.log("This is a db error");
    return res.status(400).json(err);
   }
   else if(user){
   console.log("This is a good registration", user);
   req.session.user = user._id;
   res.sendStatus(200);
   }
  })
 },

 login: function(req,res){
  /* username:? , password:? */
  var password = req.body.password;    /*for hashing of passwords in the future*/
  User.findOne({username: req.body.username, password: password}, function(err, user){
   if (err){
    console.log("This is the json error");
    return res.status(400).json(err);
   }
   else if (user){
    console.log("This is a good combo");
    req.session.user = user._id;
    res.sendStatus(200); 
   }else{
    console.log("This is the no good return msg")
    res.status(400).send({data:"Yo, Username Password combo be no good"});
   }   
  })
 },
 logout: function(req,res){
  console.log("You are out man 1");
  req.session.destroy();
  console.log("You are out man");
  res.send(200);
 },
 get: function(req,res){            //pulls userId in association with $routeParams
  User.findOne({_id: req.params.id}, function(err, user){
   if(err){
    return res.sendStatus(500);
   }else{
   res.json(user);
   }
  })
 }
}
```

User model:

```js
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
 username: {type:String, required:true, minlength:4},
 password: {type:String, required:true, minlength:4, select:false},
 topics: [{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:'Topic'}],
 answers: [{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:'Answer'}],
 comments: [{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:'Comment'}],
}, {timestamps:true});

mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

Server.js:

```js
//Node modules
var express = require('express');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var expressSession = require('express-session');
var path = require('path');


//App init
var app = express();
require('./server/config/mongoose.js');



var sessionConfig = {
 secret:'CookieMonster', // Secret name for decoding secret and such
 resave:false, // Don't resave session if no changes were made
 saveUninitialized: true, // Don't save session if there was nothing initialized
 name:'myCookie', // Sets a custom cookie name
 cookie: {
  secure: false, // This need to be true, but only on HTTPS
  httpOnly:false, // Forces cookies to only be used over http
  maxAge: 3600000
 }
}

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json({extended:true}));
app.use(expressSession(sessionConfig));

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'client')));

var routes = require('./server/config/routes.js');
routes(app);

app.listen(8000, function(){
 console.log("I'm listening...");
})
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Your get call is passing undefined as the userid - I'd start there.

Comment: Thanks tymeJV. I have been going over my user id path for hours and I'm just not seeing how it's not defined. It's probably something small that's right in front of me.

Comment: What does your route.js file look like? $routeParams.id is probably not configured correctly... How do you plan on passing in the users ID if you don't know who they are until you get to the server?